# Add class to links in delete page

Tags: webforms, navigation, theming

I want to add a class to the link in my delete content page, currently the 'delete' button itself is styled because it falls under the styling for input[type=submit] in my CSS, but the 'cancel' button is just regular text.

I also have the webform edit page with links for 'clone', 'edit' and 'delete' how would I go about adding classes to these as well?

I don't want to just add a class for all links because thats overkill in my scenario

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) in a [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function:

```
$form['buttons']['delete']['#attributes']['class'] = 'my-class';
```